# Centered brand not shrinking when scroll bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've using this navbar but when scrolling it shrinks only navbar centered brand not shrinks.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r

Comment: You want the brand to shrink when you scroll?

Comment: Yes I've added nav.navbar.navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}.But not works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.shrink` class is already being called programmatically. Use this class as a specificity hook. So that whenever scrolling is activated, and the `.shrink` class comes up, it affects the `navbar-brand` class as well.

***Disclaimer*** Right now, you do not have an image as your brand. This solution works only with your example you provided but if you replace the brand with an image you will need a different solution.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.shrink .navbar-brand {
    height: auto !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 130px;
}
```

**EDIT FOR IMAGE**

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 248px;
}

.shrink .navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah works!
But with image actually not work i've updated my snipped with image.
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r

Comment: That's what I said in my solution

Comment: Ouuuuuu yes! Thanks really :)

Comment: Again I want to resize navbar to 100px I've added this css:
.navbar-fixed-top{
height:100px;
}
But now again not shrinks! I've updated my snipped Can you help?
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r

Comment: Can you look at my snipped I've change size of navbar but now it not shrinks?